# Not getting properties in DWG file

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have been using NWC files for loading models in forge viewer. There I have some properties attached with elements and I can see them in the properties window (PFA image of properties).

I used the DWG file and converted it to NWC for loading it in the viewer.

But when I used the original DWG file to load the model in the viewer those properties are missing.

Is there a way for me to get those data in DWG files?
Is there any translation that will help me persist that?

PS: these are FAB MEP properties that can be seen in native software (AutoCAD, Navisworks) once the object enabler is installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are hitting the limitation of OE support with Model Derivatives.
I have log a wish about this:

```
DERI-7300:  Wish: support CADmep OE with DWG to SVF viewing translation
```

Sorry for the bad news.